# What is the API name of User's "Show View State in Development Mode" field?

Tags: apex, user

I have a button on a visualforce page, which updates current user's "development mode" (field's API name is UserPreferencesApexPagesDeveloperMode).  This development mode setting is to show the code-edit console on the bottom of the VF pages.  There is another option on the User page layout - "Show View State in Development Mode", which I also want to toggle, but for the life of me I can't find its API name.

Comment: Since it's availability toggles on and off with ApexPagesDeveloperMode, I strongly suspect that it's a related picklist item, but wasn't able to confirm it.

Comment: it looks like it isn't currently exposed in the API